# Python thread that monitors a script

Tags: python, multithreading

I need to create a python script that monitors another python script, specifically, some variables from it. I was thinking of creating an independent thread in the "observer script" that does this. This thread must run until the "executer script" finishes. Maybe all of this can be done inside one big script (observer+executer), I really do not know at the moment.

Is it possible at all to do this with python in windows?

Comment: Sounds like you could use some [logging](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html)

Comment: looked [here](http://www.devshed.com/c/a/Python/Basic-Threading-in-Python/1/)?

Comment: This is excelent stuff ( http://www.devshed.com/index.php?option=content&task=view&id=630&Itemid=29&limit=1&limitstart=1&mosmsg=You%20have%20already%20voted!)